# How to change airflow home from docker to local system

Tags: docker, airflow

I have installed Airflow on docker. I want to know how to change Airflow home path from docker to my local system.

ex:
airflow home (now) : `/usr/local/airflow` 
want to change to : `mysystempath`

`docker run -d -p 8080:8080 -v /path/to/dags/on/your/local/machine/:/usr/local/airflow/dags  puckel/docker-airflow webserver`

tried above not working:

**-- error message -- docker: Error response from daemon: driver failed programming external connectivity on endpoint gallant_pasteur (6f5e5a820b81847758c4e3e23a826b3bc5d4d7d67743cf55d6b01893cf427a1e): Bind for 0.0.0.0:8080 failed: port is already allocated.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you want to mount a local directory as dags folder for the airflow run within a local docker container.

Here's one example:

Given a local directory `~/Downloads/airflow_dags`, you have a DAG named `tutorial.py` copied from [here](https://airflow.apache.org/tutorial.html).

Then run an airflow container from image `puckel/docker-airflow:latest`:

```
docker run -d -p 8080 -v ~/Downloads/airflow_dags:/usr/local/airflow/dags --name airflow-webserver puckel/docker-airflow:latest webserver
```

Then you can run the following command to work with the DAG `tutorial.py`:

```
docker exec -it airflow-webserver airflow initdb
docker exec -it airflow-webserver airflow list_dags
docker exec -it airflow-webserver airflow list_tasks tutorial
```

Comment: C:\Users\karthick>docker run -d -p 8080 -v ~/Downloads/airflow_dags:/usr/local/airflow/dags -n airflow-webserver puckel/docker-airflow:latest webserver
(ERROR MESSAGE) --unknown shorthand flag: 'n' in -n
See 'docker run --help'.   Bro why we are using -n and airflow-webserver - do i have to set up any directory in my local system for airflow-webserver.

Comment: Sorry, it supposes to be `--name airflow-webserver` I used `-n airflow-webserver` mistakely

Comment: you just need a local folder to save dags. e.g., `-v C:\Users\karthick\dags:/usr/local/airflow/dags`