# Connecting apache airflow(docker) to GCP cloud

Tags: docker, google-cloud-platform, airflow

First attempt at connecting airflow, running in docker, to google cloud.
I have 2 issues:

1. Firstly, the connection between airflow and google cloud doesn't work.
2. Secondly, an alternative method is to use `apache-airflow-providers-google`, however once installed I can't import this module in the DAG.

Detailed steps followed are below. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

## PROBLEM 1

### Initial Setup

1. fetch docker-compose.yaml
2. `mkdir -p ./dags ./logs ./plugins`
3. `echo -e "AIRFLOW_UID=$(id -u)" > .env`
4. `docker-compose up airflow-init`   # initialize database
5. `docker ps` # check health of containers
   [image]

### DAG

```
# imports 
from airflow import DAG
from airflow.utils.dates import days_ago
from airflow.contrib.operators.gcs_to_bq import GoogleCloudStorageToBigQueryOperator
from airflow.contrib.operators.bigquery_operator import BigQueryOperator
# from airflow.providers.google.cloud.transfers.gcs_to_bigquery import GCSToBigQueryOperator

# default args 
default_args = {
    'owner' : 'airflow',
    'start_date' : days_ago(1)
}

# DAG
with DAG(
    'bigquery_data_load',
    schedule_interval='@hourly',
    catchup=False,
    default_args=default_args) as dag:

# tasks
    load_data= GoogleCloudStorageToBigQueryOperator(
        task_id="load_data",
        bucket='io-logistics-landing-bucket',
        source_objects=['*'],
        source_format='CSV',
        skip_leading_rows=1,
        field_delimiter=",",
        destination_project_dataset_table='io-airflow-tutorial-demo.vehicle_analytics.history',
        create_disposition='CREATE_IF_NEEDED',
        write_disposition='WRITE_APPEND', # append/overrite/write_ifempty
        bigquery_conn_id='google_cloud_defualt',
        google_cloud_storage_conn_id='google_cloud_defualt'
    )

# Dag Dependecies
load_data
```

### Connection to Google Cloud

[image]

## PROBLEM 2

Installing google providers using a docker file.

```
FROM apache/airflow:2.2.3
RUN pip install apache-airflow-providers-google==6.3.0
```

commands run

1. docker build .
2. docker-compose up

Still cannot import:
[image]

## EDIT

Airflow Webserver file path per image below, `/opt/airflow`. The key is saved in the dags folder, thus the key file path is `/opt/airflow/dags/keys/key.json`.
[image]

The connection issue persists, per below:
[image]

```
# Licensed to the Apache Software Foundation (ASF) under one
# or more contributor license agreements.  See the NOTICE file
# distributed with this work for additional information
# regarding copyright ownership.  The ASF licenses this file
# to you under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the
# "License"); you may not use this file except in compliance
# with the License.  You may obtain a copy of the License at
#
#   http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
#
# Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing,
# software distributed under the License is distributed on an
# "AS IS" BASIS, WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY
# KIND, either express or implied.  See the License for the
# specific language governing permissions and limitations
# under the License.
#

# Basic Airflow cluster configuration for CeleryExecutor with Redis and PostgreSQL.
#
# WARNING: This configuration is for local development. Do not use it in a production deployment.
#
# This configuration supports basic configuration using environment variables or an .env file
# The following variables are supported:
#
# AIRFLOW_IMAGE_NAME           - Docker image name used to run Airflow.
#                                Default: apache/airflow:2.2.3
# AIRFLOW_UID                  - User ID in Airflow containers
#                                Default: 50000
# Those configurations are useful mostly in case of standalone testing/running Airflow in test/try-out mode
#
# _AIRFLOW_WWW_USER_USERNAME   - Username for the administrator account (if requested).
#                                Default: airflow
# _AIRFLOW_WWW_USER_PASSWORD   - Password for the administrator account (if requested).
#                                Default: airflow
# _PIP_ADDITIONAL_REQUIREMENTS - Additional PIP requirements to add when starting all containers.
#                                Default: ''
#
# Feel free to modify this file to suit your needs.
---
version: '3'
x-airflow-common:
  &airflow-common
  # In order to add custom dependencies or upgrade provider packages you can use your extended image.
  # Comment the image line, place your Dockerfile in the directory where you placed the docker-compose.yaml
  # and uncomment the "build" line below, Then run `docker-compose build` to build the images.
  image: ${AIRFLOW_IMAGE_NAME:-apache/airflow:2.2.3}
  # build: .
  environment:
    &airflow-common-env
    AIRFLOW__CORE__EXECUTOR: CeleryExecutor
    AIRFLOW__CORE__SQL_ALCHEMY_CONN: postgresql+psycopg2://airflow:airflow@postgres/airflow
    AIRFLOW__CELERY__RESULT_BACKEND: db+postgresql://airflow:airflow@postgres/airflow
    AIRFLOW__CELERY__BROKER_URL: redis://:@redis:6379/0
    AIRFLOW__CORE__FERNET_KEY: ''
    AIRFLOW__CORE__DAGS_ARE_PAUSED_AT_CREATION: 'true'
    AIRFLOW__CORE__LOAD_EXAMPLES: 'False'
    AIRFLOW__API__AUTH_BACKEND: 'airflow.api.auth.backend.basic_auth'
    _PIP_ADDITIONAL_REQUIREMENTS: ${_PIP_ADDITIONAL_REQUIREMENTS:-}
  volumes:
    - ./dags:/opt/airflow/dags
    - ./logs:/opt/airflow/logs
    - ./plugins:/opt/airflow/plugins
  user: "${AIRFLOW_UID:-50000}:0"
  depends_on:
    &airflow-common-depends-on
    redis:
      condition: service_healthy
    postgres:
      condition: service_healthy

services:
  postgres:
    image: postgres:13
    environment:
      POSTGRES_USER: airflow
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: airflow
      POSTGRES_DB: airflow
    volumes:
      - postgres-db-volume:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD", "pg_isready", "-U", "airflow"]
      interval: 5s
      retries: 5
    restart: always

  redis:
    image: redis:latest
    expose:
      - 6379
    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD", "redis-cli", "ping"]
      interval: 5s
      timeout: 30s
      retries: 50
    restart: always

  airflow-webserver:
    <<: *airflow-common
    command: webserver
    ports:
      - 8080:8080
    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD", "curl", "--fail", "http://localhost:8080/health"]
      interval: 10s
      timeout: 10s
      retries: 5
    restart: always
    depends_on:
      <<: *airflow-common-depends-on
      airflow-init:
        condition: service_completed_successfully

  airflow-scheduler:
    <<: *airflow-common
    command: scheduler
    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD-SHELL", 'airflow jobs check --job-type SchedulerJob --hostname "$${HOSTNAME}"']
      interval: 10s
      timeout: 10s
      retries: 5
    restart: always
    depends_on:
      <<: *airflow-common-depends-on
      airflow-init:
        condition: service_completed_successfully

  airflow-worker:
    <<: *airflow-common
    command: celery worker
    healthcheck:
      test:
        - "CMD-SHELL"
        - 'celery --app airflow.executors.celery_executor.app inspect ping -d "celery@$${HOSTNAME}"'
      interval: 10s
      timeout: 10s
      retries: 5
    environment:
      <<: *airflow-common-env
      # Required to handle warm shutdown of the celery workers properly
      # See https://airflow.apache.org/docs/docker-stack/entrypoint.html#signal-propagation
      DUMB_INIT_SETSID: "0"
    restart: always
    depends_on:
      <<: *airflow-common-depends-on
      airflow-init:
        condition: service_completed_successfully

  airflow-triggerer:
    <<: *airflow-common
    command: triggerer
    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD-SHELL", 'airflow jobs check --job-type TriggererJob --hostname "$${HOSTNAME}"']
      interval: 10s
      timeout: 10s
      retries: 5
    restart: always
    depends_on:
      <<: *airflow-common-depends-on
      airflow-init:
        condition: service_completed_successfully

  airflow-init:
    <<: *airflow-common
    entrypoint: /bin/bash
    # yamllint disable rule:line-length
    command:
      - -c
      - |
        function ver() {
          printf "%04d%04d%04d%04d" $${1//./ }
        }
        airflow_version=$$(gosu airflow airflow version)
        airflow_version_comparable=$$(ver $${airflow_version})
        min_airflow_version=2.2.0
        min_airflow_version_comparable=$$(ver $${min_airflow_version})
        if (( airflow_version_comparable < min_airflow_version_comparable )); then
          echo
          echo -e "\033[1;31mERROR!!!: Too old Airflow version $${airflow_version}!\e[0m"
          echo "The minimum Airflow version supported: $${min_airflow_version}. Only use this or higher!"
          echo
          exit 1
        fi
        if [[ -z "${AIRFLOW_UID}" ]]; then
          echo
          echo -e "\033[1;33mWARNING!!!: AIRFLOW_UID not set!\e[0m"
          echo "If you are on Linux, you SHOULD follow the instructions below to set "
          echo "AIRFLOW_UID environment variable, otherwise files will be owned by root."
          echo "For other operating systems you can get rid of the warning with manually created .env file:"
          echo "    See: https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/start/docker.html#setting-the-right-airflow-user"
          echo
        fi
        one_meg=1048576
        mem_available=$$(($$(getconf _PHYS_PAGES) * $$(getconf PAGE_SIZE) / one_meg))
        cpus_available=$$(grep -cE 'cpu[0-9]+' /proc/stat)
        disk_available=$$(df / | tail -1 | awk '{print $$4}')
        warning_resources="false"
        if (( mem_available < 4000 )) ; then
          echo
          echo -e "\033[1;33mWARNING!!!: Not enough memory available for Docker.\e[0m"
          echo "At least 4GB of memory required. You have $$(numfmt --to iec $$((mem_available * one_meg)))"
          echo
          warning_resources="true"
        fi
        if (( cpus_available < 2 )); then
          echo
          echo -e "\033[1;33mWARNING!!!: Not enough CPUS available for Docker.\e[0m"
          echo "At least 2 CPUs recommended. You have $${cpus_available}"
          echo
          warning_resources="true"
        fi
        if (( disk_available < one_meg * 10 )); then
          echo
          echo -e "\033[1;33mWARNING!!!: Not enough Disk space available for Docker.\e[0m"
          echo "At least 10 GBs recommended. You have $$(numfmt --to iec $$((disk_available * 1024 )))"
          echo
          warning_resources="true"
        fi
        if [[ $${warning_resources} == "true" ]]; then
          echo
          echo -e "\033[1;33mWARNING!!!: You have not enough resources to run Airflow (see above)!\e[0m"
          echo "Please follow the instructions to increase amount of resources available:"
          echo "   https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/start/docker.html#before-you-begin"
          echo
        fi
        mkdir -p /sources/logs /sources/dags /sources/plugins
        chown -R "${AIRFLOW_UID}:0" /sources/{logs,dags,plugins}
        exec /entrypoint airflow version
    # yamllint enable rule:line-length
    environment:
      <<: *airflow-common-env
      _AIRFLOW_DB_UPGRADE: 'true'
      _AIRFLOW_WWW_USER_CREATE: 'true'
      _AIRFLOW_WWW_USER_USERNAME: ${_AIRFLOW_WWW_USER_USERNAME:-airflow}
      _AIRFLOW_WWW_USER_PASSWORD: ${_AIRFLOW_WWW_USER_PASSWORD:-airflow}
    user: "0:0"
    volumes:
      - .:/sources

  airflow-cli:
    <<: *airflow-common
    profiles:
      - debug
    environment:
      <<: *airflow-common-env
      CONNECTION_CHECK_MAX_COUNT: "0"
    # Workaround for entrypoint issue. See: https://github.com/apache/airflow/issues/16252
    command:
      - bash
      - -c
      - airflow

  flower:
    <<: *airflow-common
    command: celery flower
    ports:
      - 5555:5555
    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD", "curl", "--fail", "http://localhost:5555/"]
      interval: 10s
      timeout: 10s
      retries: 5
    restart: always
    depends_on:
      <<: *airflow-common-depends-on
      airflow-init:
        condition: service_completed_successfully

volumes:
  postgres-db-volume:
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For first problem, You need to check the [Reference for package extras](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/extra-packages-ref.html) page. I think you will need to verify if the provider was installed correctly `pip install 'apache-airflow[google_auth]` , `apache-airflow-providers-google`  and `apache-airflow[google]`. Also, I think you will have to manage your credentials to be able to use the operators as show on [connections](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow-providers-google/stable/connections/gcp.html) page. Also, to set up your connection you can verify the demo connections that airflow has plus this video [guide](https://youtu.be/wAyu5BN3VpY?t=1902) although a bit outdated, but it will give you an idea on how to set up your connection.

About second problem, I think you will also have to check if your installation went fine. Please check the installed list from the provider on [apache-airflow-providers-google](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow-providers-google/stable/index.html) page. Also if everything is ok, please try to run the sample that comes with [airflow for gcs](https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/main/airflow/providers/google/cloud/example_dags/example_gcs_to_bigquery.py).

Comment: Resolved Problem 2, import issue, by updating pip and re-installing packages.

Regarding problem 1, I've watched the resource and referred to [Google Cloud Connection](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow-providers-google/stable/connections/gcp.html), however the issue persists. 
I suspect the file path for airflow may be incorrect. Please verify if my attempt is valid, refer to bottom of post, under edit.

Comment: I think you will have to provide the full path for it and the check logs for the error message. For errors, if you are using docker, you should see the error when it pops up on the monitor window.  For full path, you can use `readlink -f file.txt` on your command window as show on this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5265702/how-to-get-full-path-of-a-file).

Comment: `FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/c/Users/IO/Documents/de/airflow/dags/keys/key.json'`. 
 I've done some reading and  suspect this may be resolved by mounting a local directory to webserver. Per the video [airflow-for-gcs](https://youtu.be/wAyu5BN3VpY?t=2026) or [SO page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58132463/how-to-change-airflow-home-from-docker-to-local-system).
Any thoughts on how to? Please refer to my current docker-compose file under edit above.

Comment: what is your `airflow home` path? your keys should be allocated something like this:  `/usr/local/airflow/keys/key.json` I would also avoid using under dags folder.

Comment: your `airflow` instance is running on a docker image with linux os right?

Comment: Just to clarify, the keys should be stored inside docker image running `airflow`. The path you show on your `/c/Users/IO/Documents/de/airflow/dags/keys/key.json` questions doesnt look like one. can you confirm?

Comment: I'm using [Docker Desktop WSL 2 backend](https://docs.docker.com/desktop/windows/wsl/) to run linux. Regarding the file path, i've run the following command `docker exec container_id(webserver) airflow info`, refer to image in post under edit for output of airflow/system/python paths. The airflow path is `/opt/airflow`.

Comment: what about the error message? were you able to retrieve the message information? So far I can only see `BAD REQUEST`.

Comment: Per airflow logs: `FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/usr/local/airflow/keys/key.json'`

Comment: I think to verify that you will have enter inside your container image ( If you are using docker desktop there is an option when you select the container image -> CLI) and once you are inside the docker image verify that the file exist on that path.  like if you are on  `/home`  then using `cd /usr/local/airflow/keys` with `ls` and you should be able to see your  `key.json` file.

Comment: Also, I would suggest to use to add to your volumes ( under your compose.yaml )   - `./keys:/opt/airflow/keys` one section for your keys and call it like `/opt/airflow/keys/key.json`